# my code is too cumbersome, how can I fix it?

Tags: c++

My code is similar to CTRL + C + CTRL + V, outwardly I don't like it.

In the code, only one variable changes, and everything else is the same. What are some ways you can shorten this code?

```
struct offsets {
    std::vector<DWORD> energy = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x8 };
    std::vector<DWORD> minerals = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x10 };
    std::vector<DWORD> foods = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x18 };
    std::vector<DWORD> influence = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x38 };
    std::vector<DWORD> unity = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x40 };
    std::vector<DWORD> alloys = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x4C };
    std::vector<DWORD> consumer_goods = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x54 };
};

struct cheats{
        bool energy = false;
        bool minerals = false;
        bool foods = false;
        bool influence = false;
        bool unity = false;
        bool alloys = false;
        bool consumer_goods = false;
    };

    cheats hackMenu;

uintptr_t* energy = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.energy);
uintptr_t* minerals = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.minerals);
uintptr_t* foods = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.foods);
uintptr_t* influence = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.influence);
uintptr_t* unity = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.unity);
uintptr_t* alloys = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.alloys);
uintptr_t* consumer_goods = readOffset(finallyAddress, offsetsList.consumer_goods);

if (hackMenu.minerals)
{
    *minerals += add_resource;
    hackMenu.minerals = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130)); // analog Sleep()
}

if (hackMenu.influence)
{
    *influence += add_resource;
    hackMenu.influence = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130));
}

if (hackMenu.alloys)
{
    *alloys += add_resource;
    hackMenu.alloys = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130));
}

if (hackMenu.unity)
{
    *unity += add_resource;
    hackMenu.unity = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130));
}

if (hackMenu.foods)
{
    *foods += add_resource;
    hackMenu.foods = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130));
}

if (hackMenu.consumer_goods)
{
    *consumer_goods += add_resource;
    hackMenu.consumer_goods = false;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130));
}
```

how to reduce the number of if and add it all to the function?
how to reduce the number of if and add it all to the function?

Comment: To start with, the `sleep_for` call could be outside the `if` statements, leaving you with only one such call. Secondly, for working code (a hard requirement) that you want a review of should really be posted to [the code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: what are the types of the variables? Do you know how to write a function?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  variables types uintptr_t*    ye i know how to write fucntion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With function, you can do

```
void foo(bool& m, uintptr_t* ptr, uintptr_t add_resource)
{
    if (m)
    {
        *ptr += add_resource;
        m = false;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(130));
    }
}
```

and then

```
foo(hackMenu.minerals, minerals, add_resource);
foo(hackMenu.influence, influence, add_resource);
foo(hackMenu.alloys, alloys, add_resource);
foo(hackMenu.unity, unity, add_resource);
foo(hackMenu.foods, foods, add_resource);
foo(hackMenu.consumer_goods, consumer_goods, add_resource);
```

You can even create a collection for the different variables to do a loop.

Comment: Even if the OP is still concerned about the view of repeated function call(which is highly unlikely), it can be done by inserting `hackMenu.<item>` and `<item>` in a container and call the function in a loop, which, although, I would not recommend for the sake of readability.